# NightmareJS save variable to file

Tags: json, node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

The following code works with NightmareJS and NodeJS. However I don't want to just console.log my JSON result, but want to save my JSON result to a local file.

I am aware of the .html option within Nightmare but I don't want the entire page and I want it in JSON format. Any help on saving ticketData to a local file?

```
nightmare
  .goto('https://www.stubhub.com/')
  .wait(3000)
  .type('.inputbox', 'chicago bulls')
  .mouseover('.search-action-button')
  .click('.search-action-button')
  .wait(3000)
  .evaluate(function () {
    var ticketData = {}

ticketData.team = ([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.event-title'))).map( function(x) {
  return x.innerText
});

ticketData.date = ([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.date-stamp-month-dd'))).map( function(x) {
  return x.innerText
});

ticketData.price = ([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.price'))).map( function(x) {
  return x.innerText
});

ticketData.url = ([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.event-link'))).map( function(x) {
  return x.href
});

return ticketData;
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return nightmare
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [fs module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) of phantomjs and [fs.write function](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html):

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.write('ticket_data', JSON.stringify(data), 'w');
```

Or [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) of Node.JS and [fs.writeFileSync function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options):

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('ticket_data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
.then(function (data) {
fs.writeFileSync('ticket_data', JSON.stringify(data));
//  fs.write('ticket_data', JSON.stringify(data), 'w');
//  console.log('Data = ' +JSON.stringify(data))
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same need and used the following syntax to "pretty-print" the JSON contents to the file.

```
var writeToFile = function() {
  fs.writeFile(setupFilePath, JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), function(err) {
    if(err) { 
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```

One thing to note here are the additional parameters passed to JSON.stringify() - this will indent each line 4 spaces for extra readability.  More info on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

I had to be very explicit about my file path which is defined as follows:

```
var setupFilePath = __dirname + '/../../setup_info.json';
```